# How to move out the code of a macro from an Excel document

Tags: vba, excel, version-control

We have an Excel file with a somewhat complex macro logic inside.

I would like to put that logic into a `VB` file (or similar) to be able to store it inside a source control repository (`TFS`) and branch / merge / compare it.

Is it possible to store the macro logic outside the Excel file and call it somehow? Ideally I don't want to do a copy paste of the code of the Excel to the TFS but to reference from the Excel the code stored in the TFS file.

Comment: You could save it as a XLAM file (Add-In).